# How to match only single . in file name and not two .?

Tags: linux, bash

In regex, I think I want `.*\..*` -> Match all files with any characters, single dot, all characters.

In unix filenaming pattern matching, is there a way to do this as `*.*` matches filenames with two . in them.  It will match release_4.18.1 file when I only want it to match all the release_4.18 files.

I am using github branch protection name matching so I can't do fancy commands either in bash or anything :(

Comment: "all characters" include also dot `.`. So you should change the requirements

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps

```
^[^.]*\.[^.]*$
```

- Here we match any number of non-dot characters via [^.]* then a single dot, then any number of non-dot characters again.
- As a dot in regex means match any character we escape it to match a literal dot.
- The ^ and $ are start and end of string markers so we don't match more than one thing.

Comment: This match also filenames with more than one dot!

Comment: [not any more](https://regex101.com/r/OILtDV/1)